# ldap_add error `unknown attribute in the data`

Tags: php, openldap

I am able to connect to the ldap server, the id has credentials to add users. I am able to bind to the user id without any issues. When I attempt to add an entry in ldap, I get the error message : 
`ldap_add(): Unknown attribute in the data`

```
$info["dn"] = "cn=jack,o=ldapdb";
$info["o"] = "ldapdb";
$info["cn"] = "John Jones";
$info["sn"] = "Jones";
$info["objectclass"] = "LDAPDB";


echo ldap_add($lc, "cn=jack,o=ldapdb", $info)  ? "was able to add" : "was not able to add";

echo ldap_error($lc);


ldap_close($lc);
```

The `ldap_error` gives a response of `Success` --- but, this user is not visible in `ldap_search` results.

Answer (score 0):

Probably, you don't need "dn" attribute when there is already one parameter dn in the ldap_add method.

Comment the line with this attribute i.e.

> $info["dn"] = "cn=jack,o=ldapdb";

and then execute the program once again.